# why the function call operator runs before the grouping operator if the grouping operator has higher precedence?

Tags: javascript, operators

why the function call operator runs before the grouping operator if the grouping operator has higher precedence ?

```
var c = function(){console.log('from c1')};
var c2 = function(){console.log('from c2')};
c() + (c2());
/*
results :
from c1
from c2
*/
```

tried it also...

```
var c = function(){console.log('from c1')};
var c2 = function(){console.log('from c2')};
c() + new c2();
/*
results :
from c1
from c2
*/
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The left-hand side of the `+` operator has to be evaluated first. Precedence affects how the expression is parsed. Evaluation happens after that.

Comment: brk,i want that c2 will called first and not c1

Comment: @NadavShlush then put the call to `c2()` on the left-hand side of the `+` operator. "Operator precedence" does not mean what you apparently think it means.

Comment: Parsing precedence has nothing to do with evaluation order.